# Wrong path while Expanding formulas in Excel via python (Openpyxl)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I received help in creating a code to expand formulas but I've encountered yet another problem.
It's (at least I think so) only related to format of path to another sheet.
I couldn't find anything in the documentary of openpyxl how the pathing should looks like.

So I have this example code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator

wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx")
ws = wb.active # or wb["SheetName"]

SR, SC = 2, 4 # which is D2

d = {
    "sum": ("=SUM(A2:C2)", "D2"),
    "multiply": ("=PRODUCT(A2:C2)", "E2"),
    "divide": ("=A2/B2/C2", "F2"),
    "average": ("=AVERAGE(A2:C2)", "G2")
}

for col, agg in zip(ws.iter_cols(min_row=SR, min_col=SC), d):
    for idx, cell in enumerate(col):
        cell.value = Translator(
            *d.get(agg)
        ).translate_formula(cell.coordinate)

wb.save("file.xlsx") # this is an inplace modification
```

How do I apply a path to different sheet to this part:

```
d = { 
"sum": ("=SUM(A2:C2)", "D2"), 
"multiply": ("=PRODUCT(A2:C2)", "E2"), 
"divide": ("=A2/B2/C2", "F2"), 
"average": ("=AVERAGE(A2:C2)", "G2") 
}
```

For example I need to use such line:

```
"STID": ("=VLOOKUP(BQ2,'Mapping'!$V:$Y,4,FALSE)", "BQ2"),
```

But it says that it's invalid syntax.
It's not very clear to me how exactly path to another sheet needs to look like.

Comment: show the error message. *"it says that it's invalid syntax"* does not help...

Comment: If you add that key 'STID' as is to your dictionary 'd', it would not give an error.